# вывод первого символа строки

Tags: c, строки

Подскажите, как из полученной строки вывести только первый символ каждого слова? Например, от пользователя мы получаем строку `Александр Семенюк`, после получения данной строки програма должна вывести при помощи `printf()` вывести только первые буквы полученных слов, тоисть должно выводится только `АС`.

Comment: `char z = s[0]` да и всё..

Comment: Покажите нам пожалуйста, как Вы вводите имя и фамилию.

Comment: Это задания к CS50, там подключается библиотека <cs50.h>, имя и фамилию получаем при помощи get_string

Comment: @pavel: сколько байт занимает `Ф`? Сколько байт возвращает `s[0]`?

Comment: @jfs когда я писал комментарий, про русские буквы ничего не было. Да и в целом заменится char на wchar какой-нибудь. кстати Ф может и 1 байт занимать) главное кодировку подобрать.

Comment: @ОлександрСеменюк: вся информация необходимая для ответа должна быть в самом вопросе. Какие символы являются допустимыми? (a..z, A..Z) Чем слова отделены? (пробелом `' '`)

Comment: @pavel: wchar какой-нибудь также может быть недостаточно. Преобразование кодировок на Си я бы не отнёс к категории "да и всё". Вопрос может быть простым, если его сузить сильно сильно и забыть о именах и фамилиях в реальном мире. `s[0]` возможно и является ожидаемым ответом для cs50, но практическая задача не является тривиальной.

Comment: @jfs слова отделены пробелом, что касается символов то любые, при выводе поставлю их в верхний регистр с помощью toupper().

Comment: Какого типа возвращаемое значение get_string?

Comment: О, нашёл: [char*](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.h#L51)

Comment: @vp_arth https://reference.cs50.net/cs50/get_string

Comment: там fgetc используется, о многобайтных кодировках речи нет

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) {

    const wchar_t* s = L"Александр Семенюк";
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    wprintf(L"%lc%lc\n", s[0], *(wcschr(s, L' ') + 1));
    return 0;
}
```

[Проверка онлайн](https://ideone.com/FGHj7l).

Тип `wchar_t` нужен так как мы работаем с символами вне ASCII. Далее `setlocale` задаёт UTF-8 кодировку для правильного отображения при выводе. С помощью `wprintf` выводим два символа (формат `%lc` для одиночного широкого символа):

- первый символ - это элемент строки с индексом `0`;
- второй символ - это символ, стоящий сразу за первым пробелов в строке.

Comment: Для Windows код подточить нужно (wchar_t узкий, locale лучше не трогать, а напрямую выводить)

Comment: @jfs что значит "`wchar_t` узкий"?

Comment: При чём тут utf-8? В cs50 однобайтные строки..

Comment: это значит в него не-BMP символ не поместится (к примеру,  (U+1f602)). Кроме того даже если wchar_t достаточно широк, некоторые буквы могут из нескольких Unicode символов состоять, к примеру, `ё` (U+435 U+308)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738192/вывод-первого-символа-строки-на-языке-си#comment1126267_738192

Comment: Гарвардский курс Computer Science